# how to initialise data members of a class such that those data members are objects of some other class(in C++)

Tags: c++

The code includes

class point
    {
    public:
        int x, y;
    };

```
class lineSeg
{
public:
    point p1,p2;
};

bool seg(lineSeg l1, lineSeg l2){/* code to check whether two line segments intersect or not*/}
```

int main(){ /* call function seg*/}

Function seg requires objects of class lineSeg to be passed as parameters. objects of class Point are data members of class lineSeg. How do I initialise lineSeg class data members in such a case.

Comment: Create 4 `point` objects. Create 2 `lineSeg` objects using those `point` objects. Call `seg()`.

Comment: What did you try? What did your book say? We don't do full tutorials here. We *do* help with *specific* questions you have during following a book or tutorial.

Comment: Quite confused question. Try to be more clear. It's difficult to understand what you want to do.

Comment: i basically want to create two line segments. there would be two points for a line segment. one class is the point class so as get the points of line segments n lineSeg class is to create a line segment using two points obtained (from the point class)

Comment: n Question is to find out whether two line segments intersect or not...this is found out using segIntersect function that has boolean return type and two lineSeg class objects as its parameters

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregate initialization to create temporary values on the fly:

```
seg(lineSeg{point{1, 2}, point{3, 4}}, lineSeg{point{5, 6}, point{7, 8}});
```

Or just:

```
seg(lineSeg{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, lineSeg{{5, 6}, {7, 8}});
```

Or with brace elision:

```
seg(lineSeg{1, 2, 3, 4}, lineSeg{5, 6, 7, 8});
```

Or, being completely obnoxious:

```
seg({1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8})
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
lineSeg l1{{1,2},{3,4}};
lineSeg l2{{5,6},{7,8}};

auto res = seg(l1, l2);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other solutions are better, they rely on you having the latest compiler and understanding of the language. This is simple and not very elegant, but will work on almost any compiler:

```
class point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class lineSeg
{
public:
    point p1;
    point p2;
};

bool seg(lineSeg l1,lineSeg l2)
{
    return false; // insert real code here
}

int main()
{
    lineSeg ls1;
    lineSeg ls2;

    ls1.p1.x = 0;
    ls1.p1.y = 0;
    ls1.p2.x = 5;
    ls1.p2.y = 5;

    ls2.p1.x = -1;
    ls2.p1.y = -1;
    ls2.p2.x = 1;
    ls2.p2.y = 1;

    bool result = seg(ls1, ls2);

    // do stuff with result

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: well, i know my Question was such that it directed to make two class without the use of a constructor but cud we use constructor like this:

Comment: class lineSeg{ int p1;int p2; lineSeg(int a,int b,int c,int d){p1.x=a; p1.y=b; p2.x=c; p2.y=d;}}

Comment: You would probably be better off if you used the points constructor in the initializer list of the listSeg constructor. But please refer to your book and if you have problems ask another question here, this site is not suited for chat.